# Heroku spring-jpa UniqueConstraint

Tags: heroku, spring-data-jpa

I met a problem: in my course project I use spring-jpa and create UserEntity with two unique fields. On my local machine all works perfectly well (creates unique constraints in db), but on heroku unique constraints doesn't creates.
I use java9 + spring-jpa.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "UserEntity")
@Table(name = "user_entity", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nickname"}, name = "nickname_constraint"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"}, name = "email_constraint")
})
public class UserEntity {
    private Integer id;
    private String nickname;
    private String email;
    private String passwordHash;
    private String avatarPath;
    private GameResults gameResults;

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    public UserEntity(String nickname, String email, String password) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.email = email;
        this.passwordHash = password;
    }

    public UserEntity(String nickname, String password) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.passwordHash = password;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "nickname")
    public String getNickname() {
        return this.nickname;
    }

    @Column(name = "avatar_path")
    public String getAvatarPath() {
        return avatarPath;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public GameResults getGameResults() {
        return gameResults;
    }
    // setters ommited
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: Do you have the table already created in heroku postgres and expecting the unique constraint to be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you jusermar10!
Really, the problem was that i have deployed application with incorrect jpa entity first time. After redeploying fixed version of application there weren't necessary constraints in the postgres. So dropping db and restarting all dynos helped me.